# Enforcing type of function arguments in C++

Tags: c++, function, types, parameters, enforcement

I try to achieve that a function gets passed some parameters that are all simple (e.g. std::string) but cannot be permuted.

Imagine two functions like

```cpp
void showFullName(std::string firstname, std::string lastname) {
    cout << "Hello " << firstname << " " << lastname << endl;
}

void someOtherFunction() {
    std::string a("John");
    std::string b("Doe");

    showFullName(a, b); // (1) OK
    showFullName(b, a); // (2) I am trying to prevent this
}
```

As you can see one can mix the order of function parameters - which is what I try to prevent.

My first thought was some kind of typedef, e.g.

```cpp
typedef std::string Firstname;
typedef std::string Lastname;

void showFullName(Firstname firstname, Lastname lastname)
//...
```

but (at most GNU's) c++ compiler does not behave as I want ;)

Does someone have a good solutions for this?

Comment: You mean just `class Firstname : public std::string {};` ?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal NO! **Standard library ítems are not dessigned to be inherited. Never do that.**

Comment: I know it is an overkill. Other way is to make a class Person with firstname and lastname as fields.

Comment: @Manu343726: Why not?

Comment: @Abhishek Bansal: But... imagine firstname and lastname themselves would be fields of a class, e.g. class Person. A lot of classes here for just a simple thing :-|

Comment: @SchubiDuah primarly because they doesn't define a virtual dtor. It's a clear sign of they are not designed to be inherited. Secondly, standard library containers/classes are huge monsters. Have a lot of requirements difficult to fulfill if you don't know the implementation. Again, that complexity is one of the things because they are not dessigned to be inherited.

Comment: Remember this: C++ is not like Java, inheritance is not your only (and primary) tool. Always prefer composition over inheritance. (That's exactly the way that standard libraries are supposed to be used)

Answer (score 2):

A compiler can't read your mind and know which string holds a name and which string holds a surname (they don't speak english, afterall). Two `std::string` objects are interchangeable as far compiler is concerned (and a `typedef` just creates an alias for a type, not a new type).

You can encapsulate the strings in custom classes:

```
struct Name {
    std::string str;
};

struct Lastname {
    std::string str;
};

void showFullName(Name name, Lastname lastname) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Nice, but imagine that Firstname and Lastname are elements of a class (e.g. `class Person`). Do you know any way to make it much simpler? Maybe `void showFullName(class Person::Firstname firstname, class Person::Lastname lastname)` ?